# running word2vec by using google's Colab with TPU

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, word2vec, tpu

Now I am trying to run word2vec with skipgram on Google's Colab by using tensorflow. Before running the model on my dataset, I am trying to practice the model with a practice example (https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/tensorflow_v2/notebooks/2_BasicModels/word2vec.ipynb), but I have found that running the word2vec with CPU or GPU on Colab is not the best choice - it's too slow, even for the relatively small example dataset.

That said, I am wondering if and how specifically I need to do in order to use TPU strategy for running the word2vec on Colab by using tensorflow. I have searched for relevant examples or tutorials for that, but could not find any on the Internet. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code there is using `optimizer.apply_gradients` which does not well support distributed strategy that will make best use of TPU (usually 8 tpu workers), so you can use the following code to initialize and use TPU, but it can only use 1 of the 8 workers until the code is optimized for distributed training (i.e. improve the optimizer.apply_gradients part).  with tf.device('/tpu:0'):